# I am attempting to create a C++ program that uses objects to sort integers stored in an array from greatest to smallest

Tags: c++, arrays

I am new at this - a project for my Intro to Object Oriented Programming class. Any help would be so appreciated.
So I started by creating the class BubbleSort and the member functions. sort is supposed to take an array of integers of length 10 and print them from greatest to smallest. I included a link to a bit of code my teacher gave us to help start us off with the assignment. Sorry if this is too vague, I am sure there are problems with my overall design. Thank you for your time. Also I get the following errors in Xcode 
Expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction 
and
Unused variable 'nArray'
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0Ktk.png)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// class declaration
class BubbleSort
{
public:
    BubbleSort(); //initialize nArray to contain set of unsorted numbers
    void sort(int nArray []); //sort array
private:
    int nArray[];  //stores the unsorted numbers
};


BubbleSort :: BubbleSort()  {    //default constructor
    int nArray [] = {256, 734, 201, 3, 123, 40, 99, 257, 7, 609};
}




void BubbleSort :: sort (int nArray []) { //prints the highest number

    int highest = nArray[0]; //highest value of the array
    int index = 0; //index of the highest value of the arrray
    int count = 0; //counts the time you check the array

while (count != 10) {

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (nArray[i] > highest) {
            highest = nArray[i];
            index = i;
        }
    }

    cout << "The highest value at that moment: " << highest << endl;
    nArray[index] = 0;
    highest = 0;
    count ++;
}
}



int main() {

    BubbleSort myArray; //create object
    myArray.sort(int myArray[])

return 0;
}
```

Comment: SO is not a do-my-homework service. Off-topic. Compile with all warnings and debug info : `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` then **use the debugger** `gdb` to run your program step by step, query its state, hence understanding what is wrong. Spend more time reading about C++ and about your compiler and your debugger. Look into some [C++ reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp)

Comment: Yes, the way you go about handling arrays is wrong on a fundamental level. I suggest you read up on that before attempting the task.

Comment: Why is your sort algorithm a class with a private array as member? That's useless! It should be a function.

Answer (score 2):

You declare a field which is an [array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array) without any specified dimension. This is wrong in C++. (Notice that C has [flexible array members](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member), but standard C++ don't have them).

At the very least, declare the dimension as a macro:

```
#define ARRAY_SIZE 10
```

or as a constant:

```
static constexpr int ARRAY_SIZE= 10;
```

Then declare the field with that size:

```
int nArray[ARRAY_SIZE];
```

In genuine C++ better use standard [containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container). You should want to use [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or perhaps [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) ....

Compile with all warnings and debug info : `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) then **use the debugger** [`gdb`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) to run your program step by step, query its state, hence understanding what is wrong.

Your `sort`  being a member function don't need to get the array as an argument.

You are declaring several *different* `nArray` in several [scopes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)). This is confusing, don't use synonyms (so don't declare several `nArray`-s, use different names).

**Spend more time reading** a good C++ programming book, some [C++ reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp), and the documentation of your compiler and your debugger.

Notice that [Xcode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode) is not your compiler, but just an [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) (which is running some external compiler -probably [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) or [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/)- underneath). I would recommend to run your compiler in a terminal with a command line.

Answer (score 0):

1. It's not recommended to use `using namespace std;` — because it imports all the identifiers from std. See this question on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).
2. As suggested before, it is preferable to use standard containers like std::vector
3. I understand that the assignement your teacher gave you is part of a learn process, but to sort elements of an array into ascending order you can also use [std::sort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/)